# MVC Controller ActionResult gets only the first word of the string

Tags: javascript, string, model-view-controller, controller

In my MVC application, I want to send a textarea's value to my controller.
On script side in the view, seems good, but when I debug into the controller, in the given string there is only the first word

Script:

```
var link = "/Message/ShowConversationMessages?currUsrID=" + partA + "&bodyMsg=" + $('#msg').val();
$('#reader').load(link);
```

When I alert "link" variable, or  "$('#msg').val()" it's perfect. e.g.: "This is a test message"

Controler:

```
public ActionResult ShowConversationMessages(long currUsrID = -1, string bodyMsg = "")
    {
```

When I stop here, and inspect the bodyMsg value, it contains only the first word of the string: "This"

Could you please help in this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the encodeURIComponent($('#msg').val()) solved it perfectly.

Thanks and regards